# Cleaning up formatting after deletion using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a function similar to the one below appearing in multiple files. I want to use regex to get rid of all references to `outputString`, since clearly, they're wasteful.

```
    ... other functions, class declarations, etc
    public String toString()
      {
        String outputString = "";
        return ... some stuff
         + outputString;
      }
    ... other functions, class declarations, etc
```

I'm happy to do this in multiple passes. So far I've got regexes to find the first and last line (`String outputString = "";$` and `( \+ outputString;)$`). However, I've got two problems: first, I want to get rid of the whitespace that results in deleting the two lines that refer to `outputString`. Second, I need the final `;` on the second last line to move up to the line above it.

As a bonus, I'd also like to know what's wrong with adding the line start anchor (`^`) to either of the regexes I specified. It seems like doing so would tighten them up, but when I try something like `^( \+ outputString;)$` I get zero results.

After all's said and done the function above should look like this:

```
... other functions, class declarations, etc
public String toString()
  {
     return ... some stuff;
  }
... other functions, class declarations, etc
```

Here's an example of what "some stuff" might be:

```
"name" + ":" + getName()+ "," +
            "id" + ":" + getId()+ "]" + System.getProperties().getProperty("line.separator") +
            "  " + "student = "+(getStudent()!=null?Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(getStudent())):"null")
```

Here's a concrete example:

Current:

```
public void delete()
          {
            Student existingStudent = student;
            student = null;
            if (existingStudent != null)
            {
              existingStudent.delete();
            }
          }


          public String toString()
          {
            String outputString = "";
            return super.toString() + "["+
                    "name" + ":" + getName()+ "," +
                    "id" + ":" + getId()+ "]" + System.getProperties().getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "  " + "student = "+(getStudent()!=null?Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(getStudent())):"null")
             + outputString;
          }

public String getId()
      {
        return id;
      }
```

Required:

```
public void delete()
      {
        Student existingStudent = student;
        student = null;
        if (existingStudent != null)
        {
          existingStudent.delete();
        }
      }


      public String toString()
      {
        return super.toString() + "["+
                "name" + ":" + getName()+ "," +
                "id" + ":" + getId()+ "]" + System.getProperties().getProperty("line.separator") +
                "  " + "student = "+(getStudent()!=null?Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(getStudent())):"null");
      }

public String getId()
      {
        return id;
      }
```

Comment: What does the final result looks like? It will be much better to look at that. It will do all the explaining.

Comment: @MYGz please see edits

Comment: To cover this in the general case will require building a parser, rather than a handful of regex thrown together.

Comment: Please post Full text in 1 block and Full required text after replacement in another.

Comment: @MYGz I could post an example, but I need there to be a degree of general applicability so I'm a bit hesitant. All I know for sure is that there will be a `toString()` method as I've described in each file I need to process, and that the first and last line of the `toString()` method will be as I've described above. I need to get rid of the first and last line and move the semicolon from the last line up by a single line (it needs to be the final character of the function). Do you think this is possible to do with regex?

Comment: @Adam Regular expressions are very specific. Even a single space or a dot can break them. In order to construct a general regex, will have to consider all the patterns before constructing the regex.

Comment: Before I try to come up with a list of patterns, could we do something like "1. find the `toString()` function 2. Within the area we've identified as the `toString()` function, apply the regexes you've already provided."? Are there anything like variables we could use?

Comment: @Adam As I said, Include the full current and required blocks, I can do a test run then. I'll consider making a general regex.

Comment: @MYGz I added a concrete example, is that enough? It's hard to come up with a general pattern.

Comment: @Adam Modified the 2nd pass. Try now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### 1st pass:

Find:

```
.*outputString.*\R
```

Replace with empty string.

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/g3aYnp/2

> #### 2nd pass:

Find:

```
(toString\(\)[\s\S]+\))(\s*\R\s*?\})
```

Replace:

```
$1;$2
```

https://regex101.com/r/oxsNRW/3

Comment: That works, except I need there to be a `;` after (some stuff)

Comment: Which stuff? Edit in the question.

Comment: It's in the question already. Before the replacement, there's a line of the form `return ... (some stuff)` where` ... (some stuff)` can be anything. After the replacement, that line should be `return ... (some stuff);` (notice the extra semi-colon at the end)

Comment: @Adam will require more code to cover all the cases. This one is covered.

Comment: @MYGz you can use `\R` to catch linebreak sequences platform independently, so that there is no need for _Try `\r\n` instead of `\n` if you are on windows._

Comment: @SebastianProske Thanks for bringing me out of that ignorance :D

Comment: @MYGz If you'll allow me to move the target one more time, is there a way to restrict the replacement to just the `toString()` function? Some of the files have other functions and class declarations that I don't want to add `;`s to. I've edited the original question.

Comment: @MYGz When I put the second one into Notepad ++ it says it's an invalid regular expression. It does work in the website you linked to though.

Comment: Got the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945175/why-doesnt-this-regex-work-in-notepad-windows/41945229#41945229

Comment: @Adam Great. Did the regex work for all the cases? Or it didn't?

Comment: @MYGz it did! Thanks so much for you help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the wanted part of the `return` expression does not contain any semi colons (i.e. `;`) then you can do it in one replace. Search for:

```
^ +String outputString = "";\R( +return [^;]+?)\R +\+ outputString;
```

and replace with:

```
\1;
```

The idea is to match all three lines in one go, to keep the wanted part and to add the `;`.

---

An interesting point in this replacement. My first attempt had `... return [^;]+)\R +\+ ...` and it failed whereas `... return [^;]+)\r\n +\+ ...` worked. The `\R` version appeared to leave a line-break before the final `;`. Turning on menu => **View** => **Show symbol** => **Show end of line** reveals that the greedy term within the capture group collected the `\r` and the `\R` matched only the `\n`. Changing to a non-greedy form allowed the `\R` to match the entire `\r\n`.

Comment: Perhaps include the demo link? Will be interested to see a different approach.

Comment: @MYGz What do you mean by "include the demo link"? I copied your example text into Notepad++ and used the replacement expressions I describe. What other demo is needed?

Comment: Go to https://regex101.com You can do the same thing there. And you can show it to others as well how you did it.

Comment: @MYGz Why would I want to use regex101 when I have Notepad++ and when the question is about Notepad++? You and anyone else can easily try the replacement by using Notepad++. Or, please feel free to try the expression I gave in one of those regex checking sites.