# Why doesn't this regex work in Notepad++ (Windows)?

Tags: regex, notepad++

The following regex works when I test it here: https://regex101.com/r/oxsNRW/2

`(toString\(\)[\s\S]+\))(\s*\R\s*?})`

However, when I put the same input and regex into Notepad++ on Windows 10 it says the regex is invalid. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notepad++ regex flavor is [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html), and its regex syntax is a bit different from PCRE.

In your case, escape the `}`:

```
(toString\(\)[\s\S]+\))(\s*\R\s*\})
                                ^^
```

[image]

Comment: I replaced the greedy quantifier to a lazy one after the last `\s`, but it is not that important here.